# How to format Microsoft Excel data labels without trailing decimal on round values?

Tags: excel, formatting

(Not sure if this is the best stack for this question).

What is the format to have 14500 read as $14.5K but to have 3000 read as just $3K without the trailing decimal point?
I can't seem to comprehend the correct expression from the [manual](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Since i am afterwards putting a logo in the middle of the chart using Photoshop, my solution to this is to just use Photoshop to get rid of the decimal point.
This is a KISS/fudge solution. But i will leave the question open for a real answer if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work, I formatted the cell's of the data column `4
4
4
4
3.5
13.5`, by either selecting the column and then right click and `format cells` or by right clicking on the chart and selecting `format data labels`.
I formatted this with the regular expression `$#K` so that the data then shows as 
`$4K
$4K
$4K
$4K
$4K
$14K`. 
The consequence is that the number is rounded to not include the decimal.
Now, all i needed to do was separately format the individual cell's that had decimal values by right clicking on the individual cell's and changing their format to `#.0K`.

Thus we now have, `$4K
$4K
$4K
$4K
$3.5K
$13.5K`

Also, the `,` can be used in the regex (`$#,K` for round numbers, `$#.0,K` for decimal) for data of thousands, like my original question.

 This was an acceptable solution for me because there were only two such fractional data points.
For a larger dataset, you will need to use a conditional expression to determine all the cell's that have decimal values.

One way to do this, is like so:
If your numbers are in column B, apply this formula for column C
`=B1=INT(B1)`
This will show `TRUE` if the data is of INT data type (no decimal precision) and `FALSE` if not.

Now, select column C and select `Data\Filter\Autofilter`
From the drop-down list in C1, select `FALSE` 
This will show only the decimal numbers and hide the whole numbers.
And now you can apply the relevent formatting as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not appear to support this functionality using custom format codes. However, there is a way to simulate this. Create a new column that uses the function `="$"&A1/1000&"K"`.

```
Original   ="$"&A1/1000&"K"
$3,500     $3.5K
$3,000     $3K
$14,500    $14.5K
$13,300    $13.3K
$25,000    $25K
$250,000   $250K
```

Comment: You could do custom format codes on each data point in the series, in `For/Each` loop in VBA.

Comment: @Brett Wolfington This didn't work for me. It messed up the plotted data in the chart. The data in the cells needs to be without the $ or K and then formatting the cells or chart brings that up. But the correct formatting is what i couldnt pin down, until...

Comment: @David Zemens just gave me the answer basically (thanks). I will put it up in a new answer.